# Colims over $\mathbb{N}$ in Set

Tags: category-theory

I am having a difficult time reading this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827000/inductive-limits-commute-naturally-with-binary-products-in-set) by Sebastian. I was reading his 'constructing map' and I am very confused why such colim could be understood in the following way

> We may view $\text{colim}_n(X_n)$ as the set of all sequences in $\prod_{n}X_n$, quotiented by the equivalence relation $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \sim x' = (x_1', x_2', \ldots)$ if and only if $x$ and $x'$ have a common tail.

One simple question I cannot answer is that how would one map each $X_i$ to $\prod_{n}X_n$, since this is fundamentally required by defn of a colimt? When Seb said $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ does he mean $x_1\in X_1, x_2\in X_2$ etc? or all $x_i$ just lie in $X_j$ for some $j$? Could someone please explain why could we view colim in this way?

Comment: Modulo Sebastian's typo this is btw explained e.g. in Vakil's Rising Sea or any category theory introduction.

Comment: This was pointed out to me and I have fixed my original question:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the disjoint union of the $X_i$, not the product. The way the sequences arise is by applying the maps $f_i \colon X_i \to X_{i + 1}$ to an element. So you can still *sort of* think of an element $x_k \in X_k$ as a sequence $(x_k, f_k(x_k), f_{k+1}(f_k(x_k)), ...)$, but notice that this sequence starts in $X_k$, not $X_1$. The equivalence relation is exactly as stated: two elements are equivalent if the sequences associated to them have equal tails.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense, thank you!